# ChangeNotifier isn't recognized by provider package

Tags: flutter, dart

so I have this simple code:

```
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class DataModel with ChangeNotifier{
  bool _isLoading = true;

  set isLoading(bool value){
    _isLoading = value;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  get isLoading => _isLoading;
}
```

ChangeNotifier and notifyListeners() aren't recognized.

My dependencies:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter

  provider: ^4.3.3
```

I'm very confused as to why is it happening, this is the exact setup in the installation page (and it worked in other projects).

This project is also connected to a git lab project, I don't know if it is related.

btw, it's not like that with other keywords that are in the provider package - it perfectly recognizes ChangeNotifierProvider i.e

Comment: where did you provide and consume your `DataModel`?

Comment: @AdnanAlshami currently I don't use the consume keyword, I use ChangeNotifierProvider and in it I do this:
```create: (context) => DataModel(),```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are importing an incorrect package, the correct one is `package:flutter/foundation.dart` or alternatively `package:flutter/material.dart`, try with:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class DataModel with ChangeNotifier{
  bool _isLoading = true;

  set isLoading(bool value){
    _isLoading = value;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  get isLoading => _isLoading;
}
```

`package:provider/provider.dart` is used in the files where the calls to the provider are made, not where it is defined.

See the example from the docs: https://github.com/flutter/samples/blob/master/provider_shopper/lib/models/cart.dart

A hint, in VS Code if you right click on `ChangeNotifier` and select Go to Definition, the definition can be traced to the foundation package.